# pythonのリストをfor文とrange関数で整形

Tags: python, python3

下記のようなリストをpythonのfor文とrange関数を使って、整形後のように表示させたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？　一番シンプルで分かりやすい方法であれば、やり方は問いません。

整形前

```
[('Candidate is jerk, alleges rival', 338647), ('Bears love berries, alleges bear', 253801), ('Bad things gone, say good people', 170098)]
```

整形後

```
"Candidate is jerk, alleges rival" — 338647 views
"Bears love berries, alleges bear" — 253801 views
"Bad things gone, say good people" — 170098 views
```

Comment: シンプルかどうかは判りませんが、`[('Candidate is jerk, ...` を `lst` として、`print '\n'.join([u'"%s" — %d views' % i for i in lst])` とか。

Answer (score 1):

シンプルかどうかはわかりませんが、リスト内包表記で書いてみました。
元がリストであれば、普通は`range`は使うケースはあまりありません。

```
data = [('Candidate is jerk, alleges rival', 338647), ('Bears love berries, alleges bear', 253801), ('Bad things gone, say good people', 170098)]
[print( '"%s" - %d views' % (d[0],d[1])) for d in data]
```

Comment: 「みんなのPython第３版」によると、%s等の入れ込み方は、将来廃止される予定だということです。`format`を使って、`[print( '{0} - {1} views'.format(d[0],d[1])) for d in data]`とする方が、この本、的にはお勧めなのだそうです。しかし、その時はその時だという考えもあると思います。一応参考に。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ついつい慣れで使ってしまいがちです。

Comment: 「eventually be removed」気になったので調べてみたところ、3.3から文言自体が消えたようです。
[Python 3: using %s and .format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753844/python-3-using-s-and-format)
[4.7.2. printf 形式の文字列書式化](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)
とはいえ、新しい形式に慣れていったほうがよいですね。

Comment: ここに[PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) 旧新の入れ込み方が比較されています

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-


def main() -> None:
    data = [('Candidate is jerk, alleges rival', 338647), ('Bears love berries, alleges bear', 253801), ('Bad things gone, say good people', 170098)]
    for article, view in data:
        print(f'"{article}" — {view} views')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: フォーマット付き文字列リテラルはリーダブルなので、私もこちらの表記をおすすめしたいです。ただし、Python3.6以上でなければならないので注意が必要ですね。(参考: What’s New In Python 3.6 — Python 3.6.3 ドキュメント - https://docs.python.jp/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)